# Exponent Modulo of $3^{27} \mod 10$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

The original question is:
$3^{3^3} \mod 10$
I got to $3^{27} \mod 10$
Then did the following:
$3^1 \mod 10 = 3$
$3^2 \mod 10 = 3^2 \mod10 = 9 \mod 10 = 9$
$3^4 \mod10 = 9^2 \mod10 = 81\mod10 = 1$ <-- This is where I get stuck. Could someone explain how to correctly solve this modulo?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$$3^{4n+3}=(80+1)^n\cdot3^3\equiv1\cdot27\pmod{10}\equiv?$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am still confused. Where do you get the 4n + 3? Could you further explain in detail how you would solve this?

Comment: 27=4*6+3, so your exponent is of the form 4n+3.

Answer (score 0):

$$ 3^{27} = 3^{26} \cdot 3 = 9^{13} \cdot 3 \equiv (-1)^{13}\cdot 3 = -3 \equiv 7 \bmod 10$$